В Telegram с кнопки открывается webapp приложение. Appium inspector не видит элементов на нем
Пытаюсь автоматизировать тестирование веб приложения которое открывается из бота в телеграм. Веб приложение открывается только в Telegram и не имеет десктопной версии.
Использую:
Appium для тестов,
Android Studio для эмуляции устройства,
Appium inspector для определения локаторов элементов.
После того, как я в Telegram открываю приложение - в Android Studio все отображается корректно, Appium inspector видит эту страницу, НО элементы я найти не могу, т.к. при попытке их выбрать видно, что он обращается к элементам чата страницы предыдущей страницы Telegram с которой я заходил в приложение.

Писал тех описание почему, но, страничка обновилась.. вкратце.. вам не ответят) автоматизировать приложение из бота уже абсурд) Оно уже как бы автоматизировано, оно же робот чтоб его.... дальше хуже... надеюсь поясните что вы имеете ввиду

Прошу прощения, пропустил слово "тестирование" в описании, поправил.
